# FPGA - Using TCL to increment a constant

Tags: tcl, fpga

I'm having a problem that involves an increment of a constant in a VHDL library .vhd file.
I need to create a tcl script that will look for a specific line from the library file:

```
constant a : integer :=0;
```

and will increment the `0` to a `1` and the `1` to a `2` with every run of the tcl script.

Comment: Be aware that updating the file can be fun when it comes to working with version control...

Comment: That's actually what I intend to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't very large (no more than, oh, 100MB) then the easiest way is to read it all in, find the line, do the update "in place" in memory, and then write it all back out again.

```
# read the file
set f [open theFile.vhd]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# find the line with a regular expression (remember, brace your REs!)
set RE {^\s*constant\s+a\s*:\s*integer\s*:=\s*(\d+)\s*;\s*$}
set idx [lsearch -regexp $lines $RE]

# extract the current value and update it
regexp $RE [lindex $lines $idx] -> value
incr value

# write back into the list of lines
lset lines $idx "constant a:integer := $value;"

# write the lines back to the file
set f [open the file.vhd w]
puts -nonewline $f [join $lines "\n"]
close $f
```

In this case we are using the regular expression twice, and I made the RE by taking the line and putting in whitespace matchers (`\s+`/`\s*`) and number matchers (`\d+`) in the sensible places.